# Converting image to array using Open-CV and Kreas giving different output

Tags: python, arrays, image, opencv, keras

I used cv2 and keras to convert image into array and noticed that both gives different results, why it that so ? I am reading the same image and resizing it and getting different results with both methods.

**Method 1**

```
img_array = cv2.imread("pic_data\others\C_E8415_S.png")
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (200, 200))
new_array[:,1,1]

array([239, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 247,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 239], dtype=uint8)
```

**Method 2**

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

image = image.load_img("pic_data\others\C_E8415_S.png")
image = image.resize((200,200))
image = img_to_array(image, dtype='uint8')
image[:,1,1]

array([236, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 251, 239,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 248, 241, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 248, 242, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 245, 245, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 244, 245, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 241, 248, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 241, 248, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 236], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: `keras.preprocessing.image.load_img` returns an instance of PIL `Image`, so it's actually about OpenCV vs PIL. I'm not sure there's any stated guarantee that both implementations will produce identical results, but even if there was, you're not comparing the same thing. In both cases you didn't override the default interpolation method. OpenCV uses linear interpolation by default, PIL uses Hamming by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's sth to keep in mind, `opencv` reads the images as `bgr` which is not the case of other libraries that commonly read the images as `rgb`. However, this is probably not the reason behind the differences you see as you're printing values of the channel of index 1 which is the green channel in both cases.

The other reason I can think of is the resizing operation you are applying to the image, try comparing the values before resizing to eliminate that possibility.